# Align of text in reportLab with platypus table style

Tags: reportlab, platypus

I am using ReportLab for generating PDF reports.

I have a table. I set a style for vertical align :

```
('VALIGN',(0, 0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE')
```

but in some of table cells it is not correct and some of text are out of cells!
why?
and what is the solution?

Comment: Can you provide more details? ReportLab is not perfect so you may have to do a little finagling to get what you want, but often as not it's just a matter of making sure the table's contents are set up in a way that the rendering engine can figure out what to do with them.

Comment: when i use farsi language, the VALIGN does not work  and text does not align correctly. but i use paragraph and its work and align correct

Answer (score 1):

The text in the table should be wrapped in Paragraph. Then they should stay within the width of the column.

Refer to this answer, there's an example code there too.
[Wrap text in a table reportlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726011/wrap-text-in-a-table-reportlab/10244769#10244769)