# How to use Reportlab platypus ( Align paragraph )

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to create a PDF from python using reportlab and the Playtipus module.

I want the pdf look like that :
[image: Expected result]

The problem is that i don't understand how to handle the layout.
I created a simple PageTemplate which is the main Page, with a simple Frame
But inside this simple frame, i need a flowable with "two colonne" layout.

The page template :

```
class PageOne(PageTemplate):

def __init__(self, context):
    self.context = context
    self.largeur = self.context.doc.pagesize[0]
    self.hauteur = self.context.doc.pagesize[1]

    self.simpleFrame = Frame(self.context.doc.leftMargin, self.context.doc.bottomMargin, self.context.doc.width, self.context.doc.height - 3*cm, id='normal');
    PageTemplate.__init__(self, id="PageOne", frames=[self.simpleFrame], pagesize = A4, onPage = CommonReportPdf.footer_and_header)
    print("here 1 ")   

def beforeDrawPage(self, canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    try:
        print("beforeDrawPage")
    finally:
        canvas.restoreState()
```

The custom section model (represent a part with the associated tests):

```
class CustomSection(Flowable):

def __init__(self, x=0, y=-15, width=80, height=15, title="", flowables=[]):
    Flowable.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.title = title
    self.styles = getSampleStyleSheet()        

def __repr__(self):
    return "CustomSection(w=%s)" % self.width

def _draw_title(self):
    print("draw title")
    self.canv.rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    self.canv.line(self.x, 0, 500, 0)

    p = Paragraph(self.title, style=self.styles["Normal"])
    p.wrapOn(self.canv, self.width, self.height)
    p.drawOn(self.canv, *self.coord(self.x+2, 10, mm))

def draw(self):
    self.canv.saveState()
    try:
        self._draw_title()
        # Here add SectionItemWithValue or SectionItemWithoutValue to this flowable
    finally:
        self.canv.restoreState()

def coord(self, x, y, unit=1):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726011/wrap-text-in-a-table-reportlab
    Helper class to help position flowables in Canvas objects
    """
    x, y = x * unit, self.height - y * unit
    return x, y
```

The flowables :

```
class SectionItemWithValue(Flowable):

    def __init__(self, title, result, value, x=0, y=-15, width=80, height=15):
        self.title = title
        self.result = result
        self.value = value

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.saveState()
        try:
            print("ok")
        finally:
            self.canv.restoreState()

class SectionItemWithoutValue(Flowable):

    def __init__(self, title, result, x=0, y=-15, width=80, height=15):
        self.title = title
        self.result = result

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.saveState()
        try:
            print("ok")
        finally:
            self.canv.restoreState()
```

Pdf generation class :

```
class XmlToPdf:

def __init__(self, xml_file):

    #self.root_xml = self.init_xml(xml_file)
    destination_path = "XmlToPdf.pdf"
    self.elements = []
    self.doc = BaseDocTemplate(destination_path, showBoundary=0, leftMargin=0.7 * cm, rightMargin=0.7*cm, topMargin=0.7*cm, bottomMargin=0.7*cm, pagesize=A4)
    self.simpleFrame = Frame(self.doc.leftMargin, self.doc.bottomMargin, self.doc.width, self.doc.height - 5*cm, id='normal')

def init_xml(self, xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    return tree.getroot()  

def create_pdf(self):
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

    _baseFontNameBI = tt2ps(_baseFontName, 1, 1)

    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='RightAlign', alignment=TA_RIGHT))
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='LeftAlign', alignment=TA_LEFT))

    self.elements.append(Paragraph("Frame two columns,  "*2,styles['LeftAlign'])) #  I want both on the same line
    self.elements.append(Paragraph("Frame two columns,  "*2,styles['RightAlign'])) #  I want both on the same line
    self.elements.append(PageBreak())
    self.elements.append(Paragraph("Une colonne",styles['Normal']))
    self.elements.append(PageBreak())

    textWidth = stringWidth("Test title 1  ", _baseFontNameBI, 14)
    box = CustomSection(title="Contrôle logiciels", width=textWidth)
    self.elements.append(box)

    self.elements.append(Spacer(0, 20))

    self.elements.append(Paragraph("This is a paragraph", styles["Normal"]))

    textWidth = stringWidth("Test title 2", _baseFontNameBI, 14)        
    box = CustomSection(title="Test title 2", width=textWidth)
    self.elements.append(box)        
    self.elements.append(Spacer(0, 1*inch))

    textWidth = stringWidth("Test title 3", _baseFontNameBI, 14)
    box = CustomSection(title="Test title 3", width=textWidth)
    self.elements.append(box)        
    self.elements.append(Spacer(0, 1*inch))

    textWidth = stringWidth("Test title 4", _baseFontNameBI, 14)        
    box = CustomSection(title="Test title 5", width=textWidth)
    self.elements.append(box)        
    self.elements.append(Spacer(0, 1*inch))                        

    self.doc.totalPages = 4
    templates = [PageOne(self)]

    self.doc.addPageTemplates(templates)
    self.doc.build(self.elements)
```

Im i using the right components ? Did you have some "complex" document exemple ? How to handle Layout and paragraph ? Should i use a table ?

Comment: I think a Table would indeed be the better option for your problem. You might also want to look at KeepTogether to keep the title and the title on the same page but that are details.

Comment: Yes that was my workaround. I'll do it if i can hide the table borders. But i would like to find a proper/cleaner solution

Comment: Tables are by default drawn without borders they are defined in the TableStyle so that shouldn't be a problem.